# Why won't my button center in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I've tried a few options. What is the correct way to center a button in a div. Using CSS? Bootstrap?

HTML:

```
<div class"col-md-12 text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Generate a Quote</button>
</div>
```

Comment: need to make sure that a) button css is set to display:block; b) button css margin left and right are set to auto.

Comment: `text-center` should work, but the html is malformed. the class attribute should be `class="col-md-12 text-center"` but you're missing the `=`